# Can static members in the controller of Play framework cause thread safety issue?

Tags: playframework-2.0, thread-safety

I have just started working on Play framework (**version 2.x**) and I see examples, where static members are used in the controller class (e.g. a Form), and referred in various action() methods.

Doesn't this cause thread-safety issues when concurrent requests are being posted to the same Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Play `Form` is immutable, thus it is thread safe. The only difference between having static member and local member is:

```
Form<DealFilter> form = Form.form(Entity.class).bindFromRequest();
```

this call will create two objects per request, whereas:

```
private static Form<DealFilter> form = Form.form(Entity.class);

public static Result handle(){
    form.bindFromRequest();
    return ok();
}
```

Will create one global instance, and one object per request.